# ItemsControl and Commands

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a itemscontrol in my project which contain few PathGeometries, everything works good and fine. Now i would like to assign a "MouseDown" event to one of the path using Interaction.Triggers But its not firing the command at all and i couldnot find the reason.

```
 <ItemsControl x:Name="CSListItem"  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ColorCode}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Grid/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>                  
                <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">                     
                    <Path Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1">
                        <Path.Data>
                            <RectangleGeometry Rect="{Binding Path=RectPoints}"/>
                        </Path.Data>
                    </Path>
                      <Path Fill="Black" Stroke="Black">
                         <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDown">
                             <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=Selected}"/>
                            </i:EventTrigger>
                        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <Path.Data>
                            <RectangleGeometry Rect="{Binding Path=Lines}"/>
                        </Path.Data>
                </VirtualizingStackPanel>
             </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

All the binding is Working except its not Firing any MouseDown Events

```
//ViewModel
Public RelayCommand Selected {get;private set;} 

void ExecuteSelected(object parameter)
{
 // my logic
} 

Public myViewModel()
{
 Selected = new RelayCommand(ExecuteSelected);
}
```

Comment: Show us the relevant parts of your viewmodel

Comment: @Alberto i have included some part from my viewmodel. i do have other command inside that viewmodel works just fine. The only problem its not working inside ItemsControl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the datacontext of the item is not your main viewmodel (where the `Selected` command is placed)

You should change your binding in something like:

```
<i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.Selected, ElementName=CSListItem}"/>
```